# Unable to create ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I was following the tutorial to learn how to build a student management system based on ASP.NET, but there was a problem at the beginning.

I have checked ASP.NET and web development in the Visual Studio installer, but I am still creating a project and cannot find the ASP.NET project.

Has anyone encountered this situation? Thank you all

Comment: What specific ASP.Net project do you want to create? Web Application?Console Application? Can you share the screenshot about that? Probably you need to re-install the VS

Comment: What I want to create is an asp.net application (.net framework). But when I searched during the project creation process, I couldn't find it, only blazor

Comment: Go to "Control Panel" > "Programs and Features" (or "Apps & Features" in Windows 10/11).Find Visual Studio in the list of installed programs, right-click on it, and select "Change" or "Modify."In the Visual Studio Installer window, click on "Modify".Check the "ASP.NET and web development" workload (or something similar, depending on your Visual Studio version).Make sure you select the appropriate components for ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC. Install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first open the Visual Studio installation tool to repair Visual Studio, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

If you still don't work, you can open the "Modify" Workloads of the corresponding Visual Studio in the Visual Studio installation tool to see if the ASP.NET and Web Developmment is installed. Then the Installation Details => ASP.NET and Web Developmment => Optional => View whether .Net Framework Project and item Templates.

[image]

If there is no problem above, please check the ASP.NET and Web Developmment and click "Modify" in the lower right corner. Then reinstall ASP.NET and Web Developmment.

[image]